# Django rest framework field descriptions blank

Tags: django-rest-framework

In the Django rest framework, I'm creating a documentation page using the AutoSchema class. For selected API endpoints, I'm using manual_fields to add doc entries for various fields. These entries appear on the doc page as expected, in pretty tables, but the "Description" columns are blank, even though I'm including the description arg in the coreapi.Field() constructor. How do I get the descriptions to appear in the tables?

Here is an example field definition:

```
class FooList(APIView):
''' List the Foos
'''              
schema = AutoSchema(
    manual_fields=[
    coreapi.Field(
        name='format',
    location='query',
    description='The format in which to return results. One of: api, json',
    required=False),
        ]
    )

def get(request, format=None):
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use coreschema module to describe field that api-shcema/ or api-docs/ will display correctly. example:

```
schema=coreschema.String(title='Format', description='The format in which to return results. One of: api, json'),

schema = AutoSchema(
        manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field(
            name='format',
            location='query',
            schema=coreschema.String(description='The format in which to return results. One of: api, json'),
            required=False),
            ]
        )
```

Comment: You need to add some description on how it forms an answer. Point the issue that you fixed. Otherwise, it will look like a text copied from question.